# std::set::insert() segmentation fault

Tags: c++, qt, segmentation-fault

I got SEG Fault by inserting to std::set.

When compiling with gcc it works just fine, but with qtCreator, which is needed for another part of the application, it renders a segmentation fault inside std.

Header of the class :

```
class Transceiver{
 ...
std::set<Inbox*> receivers [256];
};
```

Initialization :

```
Transceiver::Transceiver(...)
{
    ...
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 256 ; i++)
    {
        receivers[i] = std::set<Inbox*>();
        receivers[i].clear();
    }
    ...
}
```

Used here :

```
void Transceiver::addreceiver(Inbox& i , uint8_t id)
{
    receivers[id].insert(&i);
}
```

gdb backtrace: (starting at #4)

```
Thread 1 "ControllGUI" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0005e2b4 in std::less<Inbox*>::operator() (this=0x660c0, __x=@0x7effe154: 0x433550, __y=<error reading variable>)
    at /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_function.h:386
386       { return __x < __y; }
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0005e2b4 in std::less<Inbox*>::operator() (this=0x660c0, __x=@0x7effe154: 0x433550, __y=<error reading variable>)
    at /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_function.h:386
#1  0x0005e3cc in std::_Rb_tree<Inbox*, Inbox*, std::_Identity<Inbox*>, std::less<Inbox*>, std::allocator<Inbox*> >::_M_get_insert_unique_pos
    (this=0x660c0, __k=@0x7effe154: 0x433550) at /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_tree.h:1836
#2  0x0005cd5c in std::_Rb_tree<Inbox*, Inbox*, std::_Identity<Inbox*>, std::less<Inbox*>, std::allocator<Inbox*> >::_M_insert_unique<Inbox*>(Inbox*&&) (this=0x660c0, 
    __v=<unknown type in /home/pi/DT_WS1718_02_StarCar/pi/GUI/build-ControllGUI-Desktop-Debug/ControllGUI, CU 0x284fbc, DIE 0x29c590>)
    at /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_tree.h:1889
#3  0x0005bab0 in std::set<Inbox*, std::less<Inbox*>, std::allocator<Inbox*> >::insert(Inbox*&&) (this=0x660c0, 
    __x=<unknown type in /home/pi/DT_WS1718_02_StarCar/pi/GUI/build-ControllGUI-Desktop-Debug/ControllGUI, CU 0x284fbc, DIE 0x29af30>)
    at /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_set.h:492
#4  0x00059f5c in Transceiver::addreceiver (this=0x64f94, i=..., id=180 '\264') at ../../IBP/IBC_Transceiver.cpp:160
#5  0x00028788 in Inbox::listen (this=0x433550, id=180 '\264') at ../../IBP/IBC_Inbox.cpp:98
#6  0x000253b0 in SensorValuesWidget::SensorValuesWidget (this=0x484000, parent=0x7effee1c, alertThread=0x2411c0, pButtonGoBackText=..., 
    IBCPointer=0x64d94 <__libc_csu_init+76>) at ../ControllGUI/sensorvalueswidget.cpp:16
#7  0x0001b4bc in HomeWindow::showSensorValuesWidgetAfterControlMode (this=0x7effee1c) at ../ControllGUI/homewindow.cpp:132
#8  0x00061b64 in HomeWindow::qt_static_metacall (_o=0x7effee1c, _c=QMetaObject::InvokeMetaMethod, _id=8, _a=0x7effe288)
    at moc_homewindow.cpp:107
#9  0x76470524 in QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, int, int, void**) () from /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Core.so.5
#10 0x0006470c in ControllerControlModeWidget::showsensorvalueswidget (this=0x40b728) at moc_controllercontrolmodewidget.cpp:170
#11 0x00024d0c in ControllerControlModeWidget::slotShowSensorValues (this=0x40b728) at ../ControllGUI/controllercontrolmodewidget.cpp:169
#12 0x00064348 in ControllerControlModeWidget::qt_static_metacall (_o=0x40b728, _c=QMetaObject::InvokeMetaMethod, _id=6, _a=0x7effe3f4)
    at moc_controllercontrolmodewidget.cpp:101
```

In qtCreator Debugger __y of last call before segfault shows

What can be wrong ?
The sets are empty before the call and still I see a comparison being called by std.
Also (reading other questions about this) pointers are comparable by default.

Edit:Found Source of problem described in answer.

Comment: My money is on either a dangling pointer somewhere, or an insertion happening when you're iterating on the container.

Comment: What will happen with address of temporary variable `i` after `Transceiver::addreceiver` exits?

Comment: Using pointers in containers deviates from the purpose. The containers are designed to own the data.

Comment: @vahancho i points to an Inbox object which is managed by a user. The inbox component can log on and of a Transceiver. The segmentation fault is thrown in initialization. So the adress stays in the set until the destructor of the object behind i is called.

Comment: @Yashas do you mean the container does automatically call delete on pointers ?

Comment: The error is in how you create/destroy the objects you pass to addreceiver.

Comment: When you enter the constructor, the array already contains 256 empty, `sets`. There's no need to overwrite those with new empty sets, and there's no need to `clear` a set that must be empty.

Comment: @molbdnilo Indeed this line was added affterwards just in case. The debugger shows me a comparison in a set with max 1 element which is just inserted. I do not understand why the std would call such a comparison, so i assumed the sets were defaultly not empty.

Comment: unrelated, but what do you think this does: `receivers[i] = std::set<Inbox*>();`  ?

Comment: @RustyX also a just in case line to initialize empty() sets

Comment: @lars care to elaborate ?

Comment: You need Inbox comperator.

Comment: No, its just guessing. Most ppl in the comments here are guessing. 
Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

You didn't post a lot of revelant code.

Comment: The actuall error seems to happen in std::less pointer comparison, which seems strange. The code you show does not contain a explicit error, but a lot of bad style, unnessecary code and code that is vulnerable to errors.

Since you use pointers, but don't how to properly use them, its very likely you did a mistake at creation/destruction of your objects.

Comment: Post all the code needed to exhibit the problem, not just fragments that only leave open pointless guessing and speculation. You didn't even bother to show when you call `addReceiver()` and what `Inbox& i` you pass to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it was a colleague-user creating an object of Transceiver but passing wrong pointers to code, which uses it, causing undefined behavior. It caused it to fail inside code I provided, like the gdb output showed, so it was on my head.
So there are some points to remember :

- with undefined behavior even the location of the error is undefined
- trust your tests

Answer (score -1):

> `std::set<Inbox*> receivers [256]`

What you're doing here is creating an array of 256 sets of Inbox pointers. If that's really what you intended, then I recommend that as a first step to clear things up you stick with C++ and use `std::vector` or `std::array` (C++11 and above) instead:

```
std::vector<std::set<Inbox*>> receivers;

std::array<std::set<Inbox*>, 256> receivers;
```

When you adapt your code to match that change I almost expect that the source of your problem reveals itself...

As a general rule, if ever possible [don't use C-style arrays in C++](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/containers#arrays-are-evil).

Comment: "If that's really what you intended, then I recommend that as a first step to clear things up you stick with C++ and use a vector instead."

An array is what he wants then. Don't use C-arrays in C++...